# Extract(subset) two ords same time in any order with stringr in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am strugling with regex.

I have this character vector bellow:

```
   texts <- c('I-have-text-2-and-text-8','I-have-text-1-and-text-2','I-have-text-7-and-text-8','I-have-text-2-and-text-1','I-have-text-4-and-text-5','I-have-text-11-and-text-12','I-have-text-13-and-text-32','I-have-text-8-and-text-6')
```

I have two words important to me: `text-1`and `text-2`. And I need them **both**, **in any order**.

I want to extract the text with them.

The output should be: [1]'I-have-text-1-and-text-2' [2]`I-have-text-2-and-text-1`

Ive been using str_subset from `stringr`but I dont know the regex expression for this.

```
str_subset(texts, 'regex')
```

Any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str_subset` - `regex` would be to specify `text-1` followed by characters (`.*`) and then `text-2` or (`|`) in the reverse way

```
library(stringr)
str_subset(texts, 'text-1.*text-2|text-2.*text-1')
[1] "I-have-text-1-and-text-2" "I-have-text-2-and-text-1"
```

Answer (score 2):

"Both patterns in any order" sounds complicated for a single regex pattern, but trivial to do in two separate patterns:

```
texts[str_detect(texts, "text-1") & str_detect(texts, "text-2")]
# [1] "I-have-text-1-and-text-2" "I-have-text-2-and-text-1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an alternation pattern with `|` to alternate between `text-1` followed by `text-2`and vice versa:

```
grep("text-1.*text-2|text-2.*text-1", texts, value = TRUE)
[1] "I-have-text-1-and-text-2" "I-have-text-2-and-text-1"
```

The `stringr`equivalent would be:

```
str_subset(texts, "text-1.*text-2|text-2.*text-1")
```